# How to capture angular selector contents for use in component?

Tags: angular, typescript

Sorry if my language is wrong here, I'm not an angular guy; it's difficult to google for an answer when you don't know what the thing you're trying to do is even called.

I'm trying to create a context-sensitive help modal as a component with a textual title and HTML content.

The idea is I would include in a template (wherever I want some context-sensitive help) a selector like:

```
<context-help [title]="'This Particular Feature'">
    <div class="something">
      <h3>Some Subheading</h3>
      <p>My description/ content goes here!</p></div>
</context-help>
```

I would want this rendered in my component template something like this:

```
<div class="icon icon-help icon-clickable" (click)="onHelpClick()"></div>
```

...and then in my `component.ts`, I would have logic to show a modal with a title as specified with the HTML content inside it.

The `title` seems pretty straightforward to create:

```
@Input() title:string;
```

...but I'm not clear on how to collect the HTML content.  What is the mechanism for doing this?

Comment: Which HTML content you want to collect? The content inside `<context-help>` tag? It is a bit confusing

Comment: Yes.  I want to render the HTML inside the `context-help` tags in the modal.

Comment: Think what you are looking for is `<ng-content>`

Comment: Looks like your real need is a good model library to work with. Try this - https://github.com/biig-io/ngx-smart-modal

Answer (score 1):

In the modal component's template say `modal-template.html` you need to use

`<ng-content></ng-content>`

This is called **Content projection** in terms of Angular vocab. You can read more about **Content Projection** [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/)

And also you want to access the reference of the HTML template rendered use can use `@ContentChild` decorator and access its reference on `ngAfterContentInit` life-cycle hook method.
Don't forget to implement **AfterContentInit** interface to your class while doing that!

Comment: It's not really clear how I would get access to the html in the component class from your description or from the link.  Can you include an example?

Comment: What do you need to do with the HTML? In most cases, you don't need access to it. If you want to style it, you can just put the ng-content within a div that includes the desired class.

Comment: I plan on invoking a modal from the component.  Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong, but it seems like I would need to capture the html as string data and invoke a javascript method to build/ destroy the modal window, which would mean I'd need access to the content in the typescript class.  Is my plan bad?  Should I be using a different mechanism?